# rsync 100% cpu on remote machine

Tags: rsync

I observed that rsync shoot up to 100% cpu on my local server.

I've machine-A and machine-B . On machine-B I've certain files which I do compress them before moving them to an other directory and from machine-A I ran rsync to copy those compressed file from Machine-B to Machine-A with cronjob using following.

```
 rsync -v -a -e ssh user-machine-B@192.168.10.20:/media/backup/Backup/Local.tgz  /media/backup/Backup/local/2021/Jan
```

The file size after compress on Machine-B is 101Gb . I've Gig connectivity on local network that should not be a problem since both machines are on LAN .

Is there any thing wrong with parameters ? When ever the cron ran on Machine-A to fetch file from Machine-B , Machine-B shoot up to 100% cpu .

Looking forward to your kind response.

Regards

Comment: Is the copying actually happening? Does the file exist on the destination server? Is it `rsync` that uses the 100% CPU, or something else? Just an observation: `-e ssh` is not needed as `ssh` is the default already.

Comment: well file does exist on machine-B and the file is 101Gb in size . due to that CPU shootup to 100% .

Comment: Does the issue remain if you rename (or delete, or move away) the file on the destination prior to copying it with `rsync`?

Comment: once the rsync task is completed and file copied to machine-a from machine-b then cpu goes back to normal. is it due to large file size which makes rsync cpu resource hungry.

Comment: If you're doing this on a regular basis you will probably get a more efficient copy (disk space _and_ time) if you use `rsnapshot` to allow `rsync` to copy the original file tree rather than simply copying a compressed tarball of the file tree. (That may not be what you want, mind…)